# Keep dinner rolls brushed with olive oil overnight

Tags: food-safety, bread, oil, olive-oil

I received dinner rolls brushed with olive oil from take out from an Italian restaurant (part of the brown paper bad they came in became translucent during the 15 minute trip from the restaurant home due to the olive oil). I would like to keep the dinner rolls fresh for the next day. The environment I live in is 80°F and 70% humidity at night. What is the best way to do this? Seal in a plastic bag to keep the oil from oxidizing? Refrigerate, freeze, or leave on counter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good thing is that the oil won’t go rancid in a few hours, which allows you to focus more on how to keep the bread part at its best.

Don’t refrigerate and don’t freeze, the former will make them go stale, the latter can dry them out disproportionately, considering the short time. Either keep them in the closed paper bag or transfer them to a plastic bag or container.
For some rolls, overnight on the counter is also fine, but that depends a bit on how they were made.

Tomorrow, you could quickly warm them up before serving, but don’t use a too-hot oven, I would guess something around 150°C/300°F should do.